# Node post request parameters

Tags: node.js, post, request

So I'm writing a very simple POST request. When I try it in postman this work fine and i'm using the same parameters and url and headers.

The server tells me that parameters are missing. But I put the same input than in postman. So I guess i'm doing something wrong writing the options but I can't figure out what. Any idea ?

```
    var options = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: self.rippledataapiProxyHost,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Accept": "application/json"
        },
        body:JSON.stringify(parameters)
    };
    request(options, callback);
```

It seems the parameters are not taken in consideration at all. When i send wrong parameters in postman I get an error "wrong param...".
But here even if I send wrong parameters I get the error "missing param..."

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you using the `request` module or `http.request()`?

Comment: I'm using request module

Comment: make sure that JSON.stringify(parameters) is valid json.

Comment: I tested it again with http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/, this is valid json

Answer (score 0):

Implementation is correct I'm just a dummy puting the wrong url !